# Adding new key/value pair to Hazelcast

Tags: java, hashmap, client, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Let's say I have a Christmas list object that carries an ArrayList for Christmas gifts and another String for the recipient. I have the following method for this client:

```
private HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(new ClientConfig());

public void updateChristmasList(String recipientName, List<String> wishList) {
    IMap<String, ArrayList> christmasListImap = client.getMap(WISHLIST_COLLECTION_MAP);

    // Other Code
}
```

Now let's say I want to add a new list for "Amy", the IMap doesn't contain a key matching "Amy". How do I add such an entry?  Mind you, the above is mostly pseudocode, but the problem has caused me no end of trouble. The documentation hasn't helped much either. Any new IMap for Hazelcast will be empty by default I would think.

So basically, I'm trying to initialize a new key/value pair in a Hazelcast IMap. I tried using christmasListImap.put() and christmasListImap.set(), but neither of them seem to work. At the very least, I need to know how to add a new Key for the IMap to recognize.

Comment: what seems to be the problem? just `christmasListImap.put(recipientName, wishList);` should work just fine.

Comment: is it throwing any exception? I can see you are using Hazelcast Client. Do you have a member running?

Comment: Just to be clear, my understanding of Hazelcast is quite poor. You would think using .put() would do the trick, but it doesn't. The debugger just stops after the put command. It doesn't seem to be throwing an exception, or doing anything for that matter. Do I need to add an event listener or something?

Comment: I added an eventListener so that I could log the interactions with this IMap. According to JBOSS, this class is indeed throwing an exception.  HazelcastSerializationException: There is no suitable serializer for wishList. Or something along those lines.

Comment: For starters, You need to mark your wishlist objects as serializable. ( ie implement java.io.serialzable interface). There are other serialzation options available, but I would suggest you to stick with this till you get comfortable.

Comment: Are you swallowing your exceptions? You shouldn't need a listener to get the serialization exception.

Comment: Hazelcast will store your entry somewhere in the cluster, not necessarily the local node. The entry will get there over the network, so obviously it will have to be serialized. ArrayList is serializable, but not your custom class.

Comment: I'm not sure what swallowing an exception means, but I added the listeners so I could log interactions more effectively. This may or may not have had an impact on my server logs in JBOSS. Also it's worth mentioning that my wishList object is derived from an XSD, and I'm not sure if I can apply an interface in that context.

Comment: Well, that's a shame then. You can either edit the generated source code or make some complicated code that will copy from the generated objects to your custom serializable objects.

Comment: @MilesPeterson, is your problem resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the trouble, but I figured out what's wrong. It kept throwing me because I knew I already had the necessary jaxb xml binding in my wsdl to made my classes serializable, but I forgot to tag it in my pom. Now the put method works fine.

In any case, thank you all for your help.